# Passing arguments to tclsh via bash heredoc

Tags: bash, heredoc, tclsh

I have following testcase:

```
#!/bin/bash
tclsh <<EOF
puts "argv=$argv"
EOF
```

How I can pass arguments to the tclsh? The arguments must be **after** the file (as per man page of tclsh)

```
SYNOPSIS
    tclsh ?-encoding name? ?fileName arg arg ...?
```

Update:

First I will take bash command flags and use them to make arguments for tclsh:

```
tclarg1="....."
tclarg2="....."
```

Then I will have string variable with tcl:

```
SCRIPT='
    proc test{arg1 arg2} {
        some tcl commands
    }
    test ???? ????
'
```

And lastly I execute that string:

```
tclsh <<-HERE
${POPUPSCRIPT}
HERE
```

How I pass "tclarg1" and "tclarg2" to the tcl script?

The string could come from other sources (by sourcing another file) and also bash script can execute that string from multiple locations/functions.

Answer (score 1):

Heredocs are sent to the program's standard input, so your command:

```sh
tclsh <<EOF
puts "argv=$argv"
EOF
```

invokes tclsh with no arguments — not even a filename — and writes `puts "argv="` to tclsh's standard input. (Note that the `$argv` gets processed by Bash, so tclsh never sees it. To fix that, you need to write `<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF`.)

So in order to pass arguments to your tclsh script, you need to pass tclsh a filename argument, so that your arguments can go after that filename argument.

Since heredocs are sent to the program's standard input, the filename to use is just `/dev/stdin`:

```sh
tclsh /dev/stdin "$tclarg1" "$tclarg2" <<'EOF'
puts "argv=$argv"
EOF
```

Note that with this approach, tclsh won't implicitly run your `.tclshrc` at the start of your script anymore (because it only does that when it *defaults* to reading from standard input due to not being given any arguments). If you need anything from your `.tclshrc`, then you'll need to explicitly `source` it:

```sh
tclsh /dev/stdin "$tclarg1" "$tclarg2" <<'EOF'
source ~/.tclshrc
puts "argv=$argv"
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
tclsh <<EOF
puts "argv=$@"
EOF
```

Comment: I don't want to pass all arguments to tclsh. I need to prepare separate set of arguments created in the bash script.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use-case and what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky little question, because heredocs are finicky about where they appear on a command line. Also, they end up being delivered to commands as file descriptors, so a little trickery is required.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the script into a variable. Note the backticks and the single quotes around EOF
script=`cat <<'EOF'
puts "argv=$argv"
EOF`

# Supply the script to tclsh as a file descriptor in the right place in the command line
tclsh <(echo $script) "$@"
```

That seems to do the right thing.

```
bash$ /tmp/testArgPassing.sh a 'b c' d
argv=a {b c} d
```

However, I'd definitely always use a separate `.tcl` file at the point where this sort of thing would otherwise be contemplated. Argument manipulation is at least as easy in Tcl as in Bash, and doing so enables various editors to provide sane syntax highlighting too.

And locating the right `tclsh` on the `PATH` is easy with the help of `/usr/bin/env`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
puts "argv=$argv"
```